# browser caching express nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying to setup browser caching on [my website](https://atmost.fr) without any success 
There is my code on my server.js file

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
res.set({
    Expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2592000000).toUTCString()
});
next();
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build/public'),{maxAge:2592000000}));
```

Whats wrong ?

Comment: You typed fonction, I don't know if its just a typo here on SO though.

Comment: It was just a typo, In my code its function and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `maxAge` option of [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) use the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header.

> maxAge: Set the max-age property of the Cache-Control header in milliseconds or a string in ms format.

In the [Expires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) header docs you can find the following:

> If there is a `Cache-Control` header with the "max-age" or "s-maxage" directive in the response, the `Expires` header is ignored

Therefore, a possible solution is using only the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header. Next snippets sets this header inside an express middleware:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=2592000000');
    next();
});
```